# neo4j-shell readonly model can't work with index

Tags: neo4j

I modified the demo EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing.java(create node with index).
I Comment all shutdown() method,
after do it, I open the database by neo4j-shell -readonly,then I run

```
start n=node:nodes("*:*") return n;
```

I get 0 rows
if I open the database without -readonly ,and run the command above,it successed!
I am very confused about it
I tried 1.8.2 and 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We disallow read-only access to running databases because of lucene ignoring the R/O aspect and still doing merges asynchronically behind the scenes, clashing with the merge threads of the live database.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I should not shutdown the neo4j because the web is running on it,so if I want to see the new inserted node with index.How can I check it?